# using xinclude in @databasesetup dbUnit

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, dbunit, xinclude

is it possible to use xinclude in xml-files with DBUnit?

following scenario:

```
@Test
@Databasesetup("FileWithInclusions.xml")
public void exampleTest(){
...
}
```

FileWithInclusions.xml should include IncludedFile.xml since there are lots of tests using data from IncludedFile.xml.
I basically have to remove redundancies in the files.

Those versions of dbUnit are used (not sure which one exactly since im a newb, sorry):

```
        com.github.springtestdbunit version 1.2.0

        org.dbunit version 2.5.0
```

i am also not sure how the Databasesetup works, since  there are lots of different xml parsers in our project.

Which parser is used by DBUnit?
How is it parsed?
And how do i activate support for xinclusion if possible?

I would be very thankful for your help!
And if you need more detailed information just let me know. :)